# Emacs Command to Delete Up to Non-Whitespace Character

Tags: emacs, whitespace

I often want to make a multiline function call and reduce it down to one line. For example, convert...

```
function_call(
     'first_arg',
     'second')
```

to

```
function_call('first_arg', 'second')
```

Does emacs have some commands to help with this. Specifically, is there a command that will delete all whitespace from the point to the first non-whitespace character?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You might try `delete-indentation`, my favorite command for joining multiple lines into one line.  In your example, put the cursor on the line with "second" and hit <kbd>M-^</kbd> twice.  Here are the docs:

> <kbd>M-^</kbd> runs the command `delete-indentation`, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el`.
>
> It is bound to <kbd>M-^</kbd>.
>
> `(delete-indentation &optional arg)`
>
> Join this line to previous and fix up whitespace at join. If there is a fill prefix, delete it from the beginning of this line. With argument, join this line to following line.

Comment: Nice one. I was wondering where a feature like this could be found. Helps me a great lot.

Answer (score 33):

Take a look at the `fixup-whitespace` function. It comes with Emacs, in `simple.el`. Its docs are:

> Fixup white space between objects around point.
>   Leave one space or none, according to the context.

A similar function, `just-one-space`, that

> Deletes all spaces and tabs around point, leaving one space

is typically bound to <kbd>M-SPC</kbd>.

Comment: M-SPACE is "just-one-space" not "fixup-whitespace". They seem to do pretty much the same thing, though.

Answer (score 24):

> Specifically, is there a command that will delete all whitespace from the point to the first non-whitespace character?

There's a command that does almost that:

> M-\ runs the command delete-horizontal-space
>     which is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.
>
> It is bound to M-\.
>
> (delete-horizontal-space &optional backward-only)
>
> Delete all spaces and tabs around point.
>   If backward-only is non-nil, only delete them before point.

Answer (score 7):

You can always use M-z to delete upto a character.

For eg in your case:

M-z ' to delete upto the single quote (unfortunately this will delete the single quote as well, but that is a minor inconvenience).

Comment: A very useful technique. I'm developing the habit of double-tapping the key of the char to zap towards to overcome the small drawback.

Answer (score 6):

I use the following macro to "pull" the next line onto the end of the current line, compressing whitespace.

```
(defun pull-next-line() 
  (interactive) 
  (move-end-of-line 1) 
  (kill-line)
  (just-one-space))
```

This is exactly the opposite of @jrockway's `move-line-up` and of `delete-indentation`, which I find more natural. The `just-one-space` command in the macro is exactly @Mike's `M-SPACE`.

I bind `pull-next-line` to `M-J` (in analogy with Vim's `J`, for "join", command) using the following in my `.emacs`.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-J") 'pull-next-line)
```

**Example.** Calling `pull-next-line` on the first line of

```
function_call(
     'first_arg',
     'second')
```

yields

```
function_call( 'first_arg',
     'second')
```

Calling it a second time yields

```
function_call( 'first_arg', 'second')
```

Answer (score 5):

Alt-space will reduce a string of whitespace to a single space character, but it won't delete the newline.  Still, that should help a little.

To delete everything from point to the first non-whitespace (or newline), type a non-whitespace char, Alt-space, backspace (to remove final whitespace char), then backspace (to delete the char you added.

To turn the multi-line function declaration into a single-line declaration, use a combination of Alt-space, backspace, and Alt-E (goto-endofline) commands.

Comment: Thanks for the Alt-space .. just searched for that, and I knew something like that must exist. Just didn't know the name or keybinding.

Comment: This was great, I made a macro and bound it to a key.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

A rather drastic way of doing this is [Hungry-Delete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/hungry-delete) mode:

> Hungry-Delete is a minor-mode that causes deletion to delete all whitespace in the direction you are deleting.

Answer (score 3):

A slightly different approach would be creating a keyboard macro to do the job for you.
so, for creating the macro stage a general scenario like so:

```
foo


               bar
```

[a line with "foo" then a couple of lines later and with some white spaces, write "bar"]

then standing anywhere between foo and bar, do the following:

```
C-x (                    ; start recording macro
M-b                      ; move backwards to the beginning of foo
END                      ; move to the end of foo
C-space                  ; place mark
C-M-f                    ; move to the end of bar
HOME                     ; move to the beginning of the line
C-w                      ; yank out all the white space
M-SPACE                  ; leave only one space
C-x )                    ; end recording the macro
M-x name-last-kbd-macro  ; name it, call it jline or something
```

Now you can always remove all whitespace between two words with M-x one-line

Make sure you remember to save your keyboard macro by issuing M-x insert-kbd-macro somewhere in your .emacs file - this is how it looks:

```
(fset 'jline
   [?\M-b end ?\C-  ?\C-\M-f home ?\C-w escape ? ])
```

Answer (score 1):

I do this:

```
(defun move-line-up ()
  "Removes leading spaces from the current line, and then moves
the current line to the end of the previous line."
  (interactive)
  (let (start end)
    (save-excursion
      (beginning-of-line)
      ; get first non-space character, only look on this line
      (let ((search-end (save-excursion (end-of-line) (point))))
        (re-search-forward "[^[:space:]]" search-end))
      (setq end (1- (point)))
      (previous-line)
      (end-of-line)
      (setq start (point))
      (delete-region start end))
    (goto-char start)))

(defun move-next-line-up ()
  "Moves the next line to the end of the current line"
  (interactive)
  (next-line)
  (move-line-up))
```

And bind these as:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x ,") 'move-line-up)
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x .") 'move-next-line-up)
```

So to solve your problem, on the line that says "second)", just run `C-x , C-x ,`

Answer (score 1):

If you want all of your deletes to act that way, you might check out greedy-delete.